# "Opposite the mall" vs. "opposite to the mall"

Tags: prepositions

> The new showroom that he has put up **is opposite the** central mall.

I have doubts about the grammaticality of this sentence. According to my understanding, it should be:

> The new showroom that he has put up **is opposite to the** central mall.

Are both variations acceptable?

Comment: This seems to me to be merely a style choice for the literarily educated and a conditioned reflex for those who simply use their regional or national dialect without thinking first whether or not they want to include that "to". My guess is that's it's AmE vs. BrE. I don't have a problem with either one.

Comment: Visit our ESL site http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Comment: @Bill Franke: Which is AmE and which is BrE?

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I'd guess that the "opposite to" version is BrE, based on "different to", but I know that those are different structures. Just a feeling, not a fact based on specific experience. But they may both be used in both brands.

Comment: @Bill Franke: Then it seems you’re right. _Opposite to_ occurs 54 times in every 1 million words in the COCA, but 178 times in every 1 million words in the BNC. I was a little surprised, because I, as a speaker of BrE, think I would invariably say just _opposite_. But then I am only one.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: But I infer that you are literarily educated and at some time in your life made some stylistic choices that have taken root. Or that the English you acquired dictates _opposite_ instead of _opposite to_, just as mine (AmE) does.

Comment: @BillFranke: I don't recall having consciously made any stylistic choice. Perhaps it's just that I like to use as few words as possible.

Comment: Aha! Me too (except when I blog). That seems a good explanation.

Comment: I thought it depended on whether 'opposite' is being used as an adjective or as a preposition...

Comment: @RoaringFish If both 'opposite' and 'to' are used as a preposition then is it a valid sentence?

Comment: @Roaring Fish: I think we can to regard _opposite to_ as a complex preposition.

Comment: In this context, the word _opposite_ is being used in much the same way as _facing_ would be, and we would never say _facing to_. Just to add to the complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not completely definitive, but as a BrE user I would say:

'Opposite' for physical position, as in the example.

'Opposite to' for meaning, opinion, etc. as in

> ...'large' is opposite to 'small'